# How to Prepare the Data for a Logistic Regression Using SKLearn

Tags: pandas, dataframe, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas

Hello there ) I'm working on an undergraduate data analysis project and would seek guidance in regard to the following case study:

**What I'm working with:**

I have a data frame consisting of 3'891 residential units, each of which holds about 20 defining variables. I need to run individualized logistic regression models prior to testing the variables jointly.

**Current Variables:**

I want to run a logistic regression to find out whether the variable of (a) Price per gross m2 in Euros [X] can significantly predict (b) Air Conditioning (Yes or No) [Y].

**Troubleshooting:**

The issue arises when I set the variables in Python and prepare them for Sklearn's LogisticRegression() function.

The categorical variable was turned into a binary variable of 0 or 1. I can set it in the parameters without any issue.

However, when I attempt to set the X in my parameters, I get the following:

> ValueError: Expect 2D array, got 1D array instead

I understand that the table of the X values consisting of prices in euros (e.g., 5300,6210,4600) must be reformatted to turn it into a bi-dimensional array. So, I updated the data as x.reshape(-1,1). It then fixed the issue. But the results of the regression do not seem right since I have:

- Coefficient = -0.00014201
- Intercept = -5.60415911e-08
- Accuracy rate = 69.45
- Confusion Mat = [541 0] [238 0]

**The coefficient should, in theory, be positive**since the mean value of my With AC sub-data set is superior to that of the Without AC data. This means that the coefficient of X should increase the log(odds) of Y = 1, not decrease it. It's at this point that I am stuck.

I wonder if this anomaly has to do with the fact that I haven't processed my X column through **StandardScaler() to optimize the Regression model**. When I do apply StandardScaler() following my definition of x = x.reshape(-1,1), then the values of my model shift:

- Coefficient = 0.44021117
- Intercept = -0.99922939
- Accuracy Rate = 69.32
- Confusion Mat = [539 2] [237 1]

This at last corroborates the statement that an increase in X should increase Y's log(odds). Would any of you have a thought on what is the correct way to prepare the X data?

```
df = pd.read_csv('Data_file.csv',sep=',')

ac_binary_col=df['AC_Binary']
gross_col=df['Price_gross_m2']
x=np.array(gross_col)

x=x.reshape(-1,1)
y=ac_binary_col

# SPLIT TRAIN TEST

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=15)

scaler=StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled=scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled=scaler.fit_transform(X_test)

logistic_model=LogisticRegression()
logistic_model.fit(X_train_scaled,y_train)
y_pred=logistic_model.predict(X_test_scaled)

accuracy=accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)*100
confusion_mat=confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)

print('Y Predictions ',y_pred)
print('Accuracy Rate ',accuracy)
print('Confusion Mat',confusion_mat)
print('Logistic Model',logistic_model)

coefficients=logistic_model.coef_
intercept=logistic_model.intercept_

print('Coefficients ',coefficients,'\nIntercept ',intercept)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you converted x to a 2-D array, you also need to convert y to a 2-D array to ensure that they match. You can check the two by:

```
x.shape
y.shape
```

Since they are both single variables, they should result in a similar shape such as:

```
(100,1)
```

If the shape is still

```
(100,)
```

Then it is still a 1-D array. Convert it to 2-D using:

```
x.reshape(-1,1)
y.reshape(-1,1)
```

Answer (score -1):

The error you encountered, "ValueError: Expect 2D array, got 1D array instead," is because scikit-learn's LogisticRegression expects the input features (X) to be a 2D array, even if there's only one feature. When you reshaped your variable 'x' using `x.reshape(-1,1)`, it correctly converted it to a 2D array, which is the expected input for the model.

The sign of the coefficient in logistic regression does not directly indicate whether the relationship is positive or negative. Logistic regression models the log-odds (logit) of the binary outcome (Y=1) as a linear combination of the predictor variables (X). In your case, the negative coefficient means that as the price per gross m2 increases, the likelihood of air conditioning decreases. To understand the relationship between X and Y, you should interpret the coefficient in the odds or odds ratio context.

StandardScaler is used to standardize the input features, bringing them to a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1. Standardizing the features is not necessary for logistic regression, but it can help if you have other features in your dataset that are on a different scale. However, in your case, it's important to note that you should use the scaler that you fitted on the training data to transform the test data as well, instead of fitting a new scaler on the test data.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix

df = pd.read_csv('Data_file.csv', sep=',')

ac_binary_col = df['AC_Binary']
gross_col = df['Price_gross_m2']
x = np.array(gross_col).reshape(-1, 1)
y = ac_binary_col

# SPLIT TRAIN TEST
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=15)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)  # Use transform instead of fit_transform on test data

logistic_model = LogisticRegression()
logistic_model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
y_pred = logistic_model.predict(X_test_scaled)

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred) * 100
confusion_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

print('Y Predictions:', y_pred)
print('Accuracy Rate:', accuracy)
print('Confusion Matrix:', confusion_mat)
print('Logistic Model:', logistic_model)

coefficients = logistic_model.coef_
intercept = logistic_model.intercept_

print('Coefficients:', coefficients, '\nIntercept:', intercept)
```

While the coefficient sign may seem counterintuitive, it's the odds or odds ratio that will give you the direction and strength of the relationship between the predictor variable (X) and the binary outcome (Y).

Comment: Greetings Amira :-) Thank you for your contribution. Your explanation provides more clarity indeed in the definition / distinction of concepts. I'm only at the beginning of learning logistic regression. May I ask for more clarification? In your reply, you state that StandardScaler is not necessary unless variables with different scales. The results of the model vary based on whether I apply StandardScaler() or not. How do you explain that? Is the first approach correct (No SS), or the second (With SS)? Applying your suggested amendment, I obtained the results of the second approach. Thank you.

Comment: The purpose of StandardScaler is to scale (standardize) the input features, so they have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1. This scaling can be beneficial for specific machine learning algorithms, especially those that are sensitive to the scale of input features, like gradient descent-based methods (for example logistic regression).

Comment: However, logistic regression itself is not directly affected by the scale of the features, as it estimates coefficients by maximizing the likelihood function, not by gradient descent. Therefore, it's not strictly necessary to apply StandardScaler specifically for logistic regression.

Comment: The reason you might observe different results with and without StandardScaler could be Convergence, Regularization, Intercept

Comment: Convergence : Logistic regression uses an iterative optimization algorithm to find the coefficients. Rescaling the features might affect the convergence speed and stability of the algorithm, especially if features are on very different scales. If you don't use StandardScaler, it might take more iterations for the algorithm to converge, and the final coefficients might be different.

Comment: Regularization: LogisticRegression in scikit-learn by default applies L2 regularization (Ridge regularization) to the model. Regularization adds a penalty term to the coefficients, which can be influenced by the scale of the features. Standardizing features can balance the regularization impact across different variables.

Comment: Intercept: The intercept term (bias) in the logistic regression equation can be affected by the scale of the features. When using StandardScaler, the intercept might be more appropriate in some cases.

Comment: If you are interested in the interpretability of the coefficients and want to directly compare their magnitudes to understand the effect of each feature, using StandardScaler might be beneficial, especially if features are on vastly different scales.

If interpretability is not the main concern, and you are more interested in predictive performance, using StandardScaler might help with convergence and regularization, leading to potentially better model performance.